# jsoup method not found

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

i have tried importing all the imports but in jsoup

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1")
```

Connection class is not found by the comipler also same problem with the Method.post other calls are working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Jsoup API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html) The static method `Jsoup.connect(...)` returns a Connection object, not a Connect.Response. So your code looks that it may be in error.

Also, post your entire error message in full.

Also, are you importing the appropriate classes:

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

Note that this import:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
```

would not cover the Connection.Response class.

Answer (score 0):

> Add dependency file into your **build.gradle** file. And for more visit: https://jsoup.org/

```
  // jsoup HTML parser library 
     compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
```

Answer (score -1):

Download and add the latest Jsoup .JAR file; which is version 1.7.2 on date 9/march/2013

then import what follows :

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.Connection.*;
```

But note that this way you don't have to type Connection.Response; but just Response instead.
also you must add .execute() method

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1").execute();
```